# If statement in AFTER DELETE trigger not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a trigger which I would like to do something if a certain condition is met.

If a user causes the system to remove a row from a security table, and that row happens to fit particular criteria, I want to run a stored proc.  The problem that I'm running into is that the trigger behaves as though the if statement's criteria is not met.  I know that the criteria is being met, because I tried piping the variable in question into a table, and the value I came up with was correct.

If I remove the IF statement, the procedure runs (though indiscriminately...it runs as expected, regardless of the value of the personorgroup field in the deleted table, which is not what I want it to do.)

Here is the trigger:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
alter TRIGGER dbo.SecurityPersonRemoval
   ON  dbo.[security]
   AFTER delete
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @person int
    declare @thing int

    select @person = personorgroup from deleted
    select @thing = thing from deleted

    if @person = '37671721'
       exec docsadm.ethicalwall @thing

END
GO
```

Ideas?

Comment: No, no, no, no, no. `deleted` is a pseudo-table. It can contain *multiple* rows. Some of those might match your criteria. Some may not. But you need to write SQL that recognizes that assigning a column to a scalar variable, e.g. `select @person = personorgroup from deleted` is fundamentally broken.

Comment: Ideally, we either can inline the code of `docsadm.ethicalwall` such that it can apply to a *set* of values, or we re-write it to *accept* a *set* of values. It's difficult to know whether either approach is viable without seeing that code though.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement probably fails because "deleted" can contain multiple records.  Assigning the value of the select to a scalar will only return the first personID and the rest will be ignored.  If you must call docsamd.ehticalwall for each person deleted, you could use a cursor:

```
declare @personId int,
        @thingId int,
        @fetchStatus int

declare myDeletedPeople cursor for select personorgroup, thing from deleted readonly

open myDeletedPeople

fetch myDeletedPeople into @personId, @thingId

select @fetchStatus = @@FETCH_STATUS

while (@fetchStatus=0)
begin

       if(@personId = '37671721')
       begin
           exec docsadm.ethicalwall @thingId
       end

   fetch myDeletedPeople into @personId, @thingId

   select @fetchStatus = @@FETCH_STATUS

end

close myDeletedPeople
deallocate myDeletedPeople
```

Comment: "first" is ill-defined. In theory, `@person` and `@thing` may be assigned values from different rows. And there may be other approaches rather than a cursor.

Comment: Out of interest, is there any particular reason you favour capturing `@@FETCH_STATUS` into a local variable rather than just accessing it in the `while` test?

Comment: Force of habit.  Just in case I did something else that may have changed @@FETCH_STATUS.  Not valid in this case, but if I follow the same pattern all the time, I don't burn myself.  I use the same pattern with @@ROWCOUNT.

Comment: In this situation, there is always only one row deleted. So in theory, I *could* use first.  But I'd rather go with a cursor.